# How to setup swaggerUI for NodeJS Serverless framework?

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-ui, serverless-framework, swagger-2.0

Need help your to implement the swaggerUI for NodeJS Serverless framework,
I already have swagger installed and API documentation is also generate successfully(in openapi.yml) and tested documentation successfully on `https://editor.swagger.io/`.
But I want to implement swaggerUI for local and AWS serverless also for different environment.
I also gone through the packages like `aws-serverless-swagger-ui` but no examples found.